# How to disable DialogFragment to resize once dialog is displayed?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, autosize

I'm using a listview in a DialogFragment contained in a LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/dialog_main_margin" >

<com.modelmakertools.simplemind.DragSortListView
    android:id="@+id/drag_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where DragSortListView is based on a 3rd party ListView descendant that allows rearranging items using a draghandle image.

All works OK when this code is used in a (full screen) activity, but when used in a android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment, dragging an item causes the dialog + listview combi to continuesly update the dialog size. This causes dragging to be extremely slow and I see a lot of LogCat messages:

```
06-06 15:37:07.833: I/Choreographer(17281): Skipped 166 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

To locate the source of the problem, I changed the width and height of the listview to a fixed 400dp (rather than match_parent / wrap_content). Fixing the size completely eliminates the problem.
Hence my question: is there a way to avoid the dialog fragment to adjust its size once it has been layed out once?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to stop the listview updating the dialog size with the code below.
However, it turns out, this only solves part of the problem: until the list is "fixated" loading is still very slow. But that has another cause that is beyond the scope of this question/answer

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Fixate the listview height once the listview has been measured rather than keeping it at "wrap_content"
    // This drastically improves rearrange performance.
    if (_listView != null) {
        _listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fixateListViewHeight();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}

private void fixateListViewHeight() {
    if (_listView != null) {
        int h = _listView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h != 0) {
            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) _listView.getLayoutParams();
            if (params != null)
                params.height = h;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `windowSoftInputMode` property to `adjustNothing` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the activities that use the dialog fragment.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
...
```

Comment: That won't work as I do need the initial adjustment to auto size the dialog. Also, it would disable auto-sizing for all other dialogs.

Comment: This adjust is for the soft keyboard, then on show it will be overlap the current view.

Comment: Ah, I cannot use that as I need the soft keyboard to shrink the activity content view.